# compile cross gcc: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile

Tags: macos, cross-compiling, gcc4

I was following the instructions to build my own compile toolchain on my os x,and I do exactly what they suggested.But when I compile the gcc , the command is 'make all-target-libgcc' ,the error shows up .
I think I had compile the binutil correctly, and the command 'i386-jos-elf-objdump -I' produce the output is alright.
The instructions page is https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2014/tools.html.
The config.log file is :

```
⁃     $ ../configure --prefix=/usr/local --target=i386-jos-elf --disable-werror --disable-libssp --disable-libmudflap --with-newlib --without-headers --enable-languages=c CC=/usr/bin/gcc
⁃   
⁃   ## --------- ##
⁃   ## Platform. ##
⁃   ## --------- ##
⁃   
⁃   hostname = huangxiaoshuaideMacBook-Air.local
⁃   uname -m = x86_64
⁃   uname -r = 16.6.0
⁃   uname -s = Darwin
⁃   uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 16.6.0: Fri Apr 14 16:21:16 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.60.24~6/RELEASE_X86_64
⁃   
⁃   /usr/bin/uname -p = i386
⁃   /bin/uname -X     = unknown
⁃   
⁃   /bin/arch              = unknown
⁃   /usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
⁃   /usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
⁃   /usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
⁃    Darwin Kernel Version 16.6.0: Fri Apr 14 16:21:16 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.60.24~6/RELEASE_X86_64
⁃   Kernel configured for up to 4 processors.
⁃   2 processors are physically available.
⁃   4 processors are logically available.
⁃   Processor type: x86_64h (Intel x86-64h Haswell)
⁃   Processors active: 0 1 2 3
⁃   Primary memory available: 8.00 gigabytes
⁃   Default processor set: 261 tasks, 868 threads, 4 processors
⁃   Load average: 1.33, Mach factor: 2.66
⁃   /bin/machine           = unknown
⁃   /usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
⁃   /bin/universe          = unknown
⁃   
⁃   PATH: /usr/local/opt/gettext/bin
⁃   PATH: /Users/hxs/anaconda/bin
⁃   PATH: /Library/InternetPlug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin
⁃   PATH: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin
⁃   PATH: /bin
⁃   PATH: /usr/local/bin
⁃   PATH: /usr/bin
⁃   PATH: /bin
⁃   PATH: /usr/sbin
⁃   PATH: /sbin
⁃   PATH: /usr/local/mysql/bin
⁃   PATH: export
⁃   PATH: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.44/bin
⁃   
⁃   
⁃   ## ----------- ##
⁃   ## Core tests. ##
⁃   ## ----------- ##
⁃   
⁃   configure:2222: checking build system type
⁃   configure:2236: result: x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0
⁃   configure:2283: checking host system type
⁃   configure:2296: result: x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0
⁃   configure:2316: checking target system type
⁃   configure:2329: result: i386-jos-elf
⁃   configure:2383: checking for a BSD-compatible install
⁃   configure:2451: result: /usr/bin/install -c
⁃   configure:2462: checking whether ln works
⁃   configure:2484: result: yes
⁃   configure:2488: checking whether ln -s works
⁃   configure:2492: result: yes
⁃   configure:2499: checking for a sed that does not truncate output
⁃   configure:2563: result: /usr/bin/sed
⁃   configure:2572: checking for gawk
⁃   configure:2602: result: no
⁃   configure:2572: checking for mawk
⁃   configure:2602: result: no
⁃   configure:2572: checking for nawk
⁃   configure:2602: result: no
⁃   configure:2572: checking for awk
⁃   configure:2588: found /usr/bin/awk
⁃   configure:2599: result: awk
⁃   configure:3919: checking for gcc
⁃   configure:3946: result: /usr/bin/gcc
⁃   configure:4175: checking for C compiler version
⁃   configure:4184: /usr/bin/gcc --version >&5
⁃   gcc (Homebrew GCC 4.6.4_2) 4.6.4
⁃   Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
⁃   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
⁃   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
⁃   
⁃   configure:4195: $? = 0
⁃   configure:4184: /usr/bin/gcc -v >&5
⁃   Using built-in specs.
⁃   COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/gcc
⁃   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@4.6/4.6.4_2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0/4.6.4/lto-wrapper
⁃   Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0
⁃   Configured with: ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@4.6/4.6.4_2 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++ --program-suffix=-4.6 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp@4 --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr@2 --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc@0.8 --with-ppl=/usr/local/opt/ppl@0.11 --with-cloog=/usr/local/opt/cloog@0.15 --with-system-zlib --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-stage1-checking --enable-checking=release --enable-lto --enable-plugin --disable-werror --with-pkgversion='Homebrew GCC 4.6.4_2' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues MAKEINFO=missing --disable-nls --enable-multilib
⁃   Thread model: posix
⁃   gcc version 4.6.4 (Homebrew GCC 4.6.4_2) 
⁃   configure:4195: $? = 0
⁃   configure:4184: /usr/bin/gcc -V >&5
⁃   gcc: error: unrecognized option '-V'
⁃   gcc: fatal error: no input files
⁃   compilation terminated.
⁃   configure:4195: $? = 1
⁃   configure:4184: /usr/bin/gcc -qversion >&5
⁃   gcc: error: unrecognized option '-qversion'
⁃   gcc: fatal error: no input files
⁃   compilation terminated.
⁃   configure:4195: $? = 1
⁃   configure:4215: checking for C compiler default output file name
⁃   configure:4237: /usr/bin/gcc    conftest.c  >&5
⁃   configure:4241: $? = 0
⁃   configure:4278: result: a.out
⁃   configure:4294: checking whether the C compiler works
⁃   configure:4303: ./a.out
⁃   configure:4307: $? = 0
⁃   configure:4322: result: yes
⁃   configure:4329: checking whether we are cross compiling
⁃   configure:4331: result: no
⁃   configure:4334: checking for suffix of executables
⁃   configure:4341: /usr/bin/gcc -o conftest    conftest.c  >&5
⁃   configure:4345: $? = 0
⁃   configure:4367: result: 
⁃   configure:4373: checking for suffix of object files
⁃   configure:4395: /usr/bin/gcc -c   conftest.c >&5
⁃   configure:4399: $? = 0
⁃   configure:4420: result: o
⁃   configure:4424: checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler
⁃   configure:4443: /usr/bin/gcc -c   conftest.c >&5
⁃   configure:4443: $? = 0
⁃   configure:4452: result: yes
⁃   configure:4461: checking whether /usr/bin/gcc accepts -g
⁃   configure:4481: /usr/bin/gcc -c -g  conftest.c >&5
⁃   configure:4481: $? = 0
⁃   configure:4522: result: yes
⁃   configure:4539: checking for /usr/bin/gcc option to accept ISO C89
⁃   configure:4603: /usr/bin/gcc  -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
⁃   configure:4603: $? = 0
⁃   configure:4616: result: none needed
⁃   configure:4694: checking for g++
⁃   configure:4710: found /usr/bin/g++
⁃   configure:4721: result: g++
⁃   configure:4748: checking for C++ compiler version
⁃   configure:4757: g++ --version >&5
⁃   Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
⁃   Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0
⁃   Thread model: posix
⁃   InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
⁃   Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
⁃   configure:4768: $? = 0
⁃   configure:4757: g++ -v >&5
⁃   Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
⁃   Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
⁃   Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0
⁃   Thread model: posix
⁃   InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
⁃   configure:4768: $? = 0
⁃   configure:4757: g++ -V >&5
⁃   clang: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
⁃   clang: error: no input files
⁃   configure:4768: $? = 1
⁃   configure:4757: g++ -qversion >&5
⁃   clang: error: unknown argument: '-qversion'
⁃   clang: error: no input files
⁃   configure:4768: $? = 1
⁃   configure:4772: checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler
⁃   configure:4791: g++ -c   conftest.cpp >&5
⁃   configure:4791: $? = 0
⁃   configure:4800: result: yes
⁃   configure:4809: checking whether g++ accepts -g
⁃   configure:4829: g++ -c -g  conftest.cpp >&5
⁃   configure:4829: $? = 0
⁃   configure:4870: result: yes
⁃   configure:4959: checking for gnatbind
⁃   configure:4989: result: no
⁃   configure:5051: checking for gnatmake
⁃   configure:5081: result: no
⁃   configure:5100: checking whether compiler driver understands Ada
⁃   configure:5123: result: no
⁃   configure:5132: checking how to compare bootstrapped objects
⁃   configure:5157: result: cmp --ignore-initial=16 $$f1 $$f2
⁃   configure:5173: checking for objdir
⁃   configure:5188: result: .libs
⁃   configure:5354: checking for the correct version of gmp.h
⁃   configure:5374: /usr/bin/gcc -c -g -O2   conftest.c >&5
⁃   configure:5374: $? = 0
⁃   configure:5392: /usr/bin/gcc -c -g -O2   conftest.c >&5
⁃   configure:5392: $? = 0
⁃   configure:5393: result: yes
⁃   configure:5409: checking for the correct version of mpfr.h
⁃   configure:5427: /usr/bin/gcc -c -g -O2   conftest.c >&5
⁃   configure:5427: $? = 0
⁃   configure:5444: /usr/bin/gcc -c -g -O2   conftest.c >&5
⁃   configure:5444: $? = 0
⁃   configure:5445: result: yes
⁃   configure:5462: checking for the correct version of mpc.h
⁃   configure:5479: /usr/bin/gcc -c -g -O2   conftest.c >&5
⁃   configure:5479: $? = 0
⁃   configure:5495: /usr/bin/gcc -c -g -O2   conftest.c >&5
⁃   configure:5495: $? = 0
⁃   configure:5496: result: yes
⁃   configure:5514: checking for the correct version of the gmp/mpfr/mpc libraries
⁃   configure:5545: /usr/bin/gcc -o conftest -g -O2    conftest.c  -lmpc -lmpfr -lgmp >&5
⁃   configure:5545: $? = 0
⁃   configure:5546: result: yes
⁃   configure:5730: checking for PWL_handle_timeout in -lpwl
⁃   configure:5755: /usr/bin/gcc -o conftest -g -O2    conftest.c -lpwl   >&5
⁃   ld: library not found for -lpwl
⁃   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
⁃   configure:5755: $? = 1
⁃   configure: failed program was:
⁃   | /* confdefs.h */
⁃   | #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
⁃   | #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
⁃   | #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
⁃   | #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
⁃   | #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
⁃   | #define PACKAGE_URL ""
⁃   | #define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"
⁃   | /* end confdefs.h.  */
⁃   | 
⁃   | /* Override any GCC internal prototype to avoid an error.
⁃   |    Use char because int might match the return type of a GCC
⁃   |    builtin and then its argument prototype would still apply.  */
⁃   | #ifdef __cplusplus
⁃   | extern "C"
⁃   | #endif
⁃   | char PWL_handle_timeout ();
⁃   | int
⁃   | main ()
⁃   | {
⁃   | return PWL_handle_timeout ();
⁃   |   ;
⁃   |   return 0;
⁃   | }
⁃   configure:5764: result: no
⁃   configure:5778: checking for version 0.11 (revision 0 or later) of PPL
⁃   configure:5795: /usr/bin/gcc -c -g -O2    conftest.c >&5
⁃   conftest.c:10:19: fatal error: ppl_c.h: No such file or directory
⁃   compilation terminated.
⁃   configure:5795: $? = 1
⁃   configure: failed program was:
⁃   | /* confdefs.h */
⁃   | #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
⁃   | #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
⁃   | #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
⁃   | #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
⁃   | #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
⁃   | #define PACKAGE_URL ""
⁃   | #define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"
⁃   | /* end confdefs.h.  */
⁃   | #include "ppl_c.h"
⁃   | int
⁃   | main ()
⁃   | {
⁃   | 
⁃   |     #if PPL_VERSION_MAJOR != 0 || PPL_VERSION_MINOR < 11
⁃   |     choke me
⁃   |     #endif
⁃   | 
⁃   |   ;
⁃   |   return 0;
⁃   | }
⁃   configure:5799: result: no
⁃   configure:7245: checking for default BUILD_CONFIG
⁃   configure:7277: result: 
⁃   configure:7767: checking for bison
⁃   configure:7783: found /usr/bin/bison
⁃   configure:7794: result: bison -y
⁃   configure:7815: checking for bison
⁃   configure:7831: found /usr/bin/bison
⁃   configure:7842: result: bison
⁃   configure:7862: checking for gm4
⁃   configure:7878: found /usr/bin/gm4
⁃   configure:7889: result: gm4
⁃   configure:7909: checking for flex
⁃   configure:7925: found /usr/bin/flex
⁃   configure:7936: result: flex
⁃   configure:7957: checking for flex
⁃   configure:7973: found /usr/bin/flex
⁃   configure:7984: result: flex
⁃   configure:8004: checking for makeinfo
⁃   configure:8020: found /usr/bin/makeinfo
⁃   configure:8031: result: makeinfo
⁃   configure:8065: checking for expect
⁃   configure:8081: found /usr/bin/expect
⁃   configure:8092: result: expect
⁃   configure:8114: checking for runtest
⁃   configure:8144: result: no
⁃   configure:8259: checking for ar
⁃   configure:8275: found /usr/bin/ar
⁃   configure:8286: result: ar
⁃   configure:8400: checking for as
⁃   configure:8416: found /usr/bin/as
⁃   configure:8427: result: as
⁃   configure:8541: checking for dlltool
⁃   configure:8571: result: no
⁃   configure:8682: checking for ld
⁃   configure:8698: found /usr/bin/ld
⁃   configure:8709: result: ld
⁃   configure:8823: checking for lipo
⁃   configure:8839: found /usr/bin/lipo
⁃   configure:8850: result: lipo
⁃   configure:8964: checking for nm
⁃   configure:8980: found /usr/bin/nm
⁃   configure:8991: result: nm
⁃   configure:9105: checking for ranlib
⁃   configure:9121: found /usr/bin/ranlib
⁃   configure:9132: result: ranlib
⁃   configure:9241: checking for strip
⁃   configure:9257: found /usr/bin/strip
⁃   configure:9268: result: strip
⁃   configure:9377: checking for windres
⁃   configure:9407: result: no
⁃   configure:9518: checking for windmc
⁃   configure:9548: result: no
⁃   configure:9659: checking for objcopy
⁃   configure:9689: result: no
⁃   configure:9800: checking for objdump
⁃   configure:9816: found /usr/bin/objdump
⁃   configure:9827: result: objdump
⁃   configure:9941: checking for i386-jos-elf-cc
⁃   configure:9971: result: no
⁃   configure:9941: checking for i386-jos-elf-gcc
⁃   configure:9957: found /usr/local/bin/i386-jos-elf-gcc
⁃   configure:9968: result: i386-jos-elf-gcc
⁃   configure:10102: checking for i386-jos-elf-c++
⁃   configure:10132: result: no
⁃   configure:10102: checking for i386-jos-elf-g++
⁃   configure:10132: result: no
⁃   configure:10102: checking for i386-jos-elf-cxx
⁃   configure:10132: result: no
⁃   configure:10102: checking for i386-jos-elf-gxx
⁃   configure:10132: result: no
⁃   configure:10263: checking for i386-jos-elf-gcc
⁃   configure:10279: found /usr/local/bin/i386-jos-elf-gcc
⁃   configure:10290: result: i386-jos-elf-gcc
⁃   configure:10419: checking for i386-jos-elf-gcj
⁃   configure:10449: result: no
⁃   configure:10580: checking for i386-jos-elf-gfortran
⁃   configure:10610: result: no
⁃   configure:10741: checking for i386-jos-elf-gccgo
⁃   configure:10771: result: no
⁃   configure:10871: checking for ar
⁃   configure:10889: found /usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin/ar
⁃   configure:10901: result: /usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin/ar
⁃   configure:11101: checking for as
⁃   configure:11119: found /usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin/as
⁃   configure:11131: result: /usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin/as
⁃   configure:11331: checking for dlltool
⁃   configure:11364: result: no
⁃   configure:11442: checking for i386-jos-elf-dlltool
⁃   configure:11472: result: no
⁃   configure:11561: checking for ld
⁃   configure:11579: found /usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin/ld
⁃   configure:11591: result: /usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin/ld
⁃   configure:11791: checking for lipo
⁃   configure:11824: result: no
⁃   configure:11902: checking for i386-jos-elf-lipo
⁃   configure:11932: result: no
⁃   configure:12021: checking for nm
⁃   configure:12039: found /usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin/nm
⁃   configure:12051: result: /usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin/nm
⁃   configure:12251: checking for objdump
⁃   configure:12269: found /usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin/objdump
⁃   configure:12281: result: /usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin/objdump
⁃   configure:12481: checking for ranlib
⁃   configure:12499: found /usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin/ranlib
⁃   configure:12511: result: /usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin/ranlib
⁃   configure:12711: checking for strip
⁃   configure:12729: found /usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin/strip
⁃   configure:12741: result: /usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin/strip
⁃   configure:12941: checking for windres
⁃   configure:12974: result: no
⁃   configure:13052: checking for i386-jos-elf-windres
⁃   configure:13082: result: no
⁃   configure:13171: checking for windmc
⁃   configure:13204: result: no
⁃   configure:13282: checking for i386-jos-elf-windmc
⁃   configure:13312: result: no
⁃   configure:13379: checking where to find the target ar
⁃   configure:13407: result: pre-installed in /usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin
⁃   configure:13421: checking where to find the target as
⁃   configure:13449: result: pre-installed in /usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin
⁃   configure:13463: checking where to find the target cc
⁃   configure:13486: result: just compiled
⁃   configure:13505: checking where to find the target c++
⁃   configure:13545: result: pre-installed
⁃   configure:13550: checking where to find the target c++ for libstdc++
⁃   configure:13590: result: pre-installed
⁃   configure:13595: checking where to find the target dlltool
⁃   configure:13632: result: pre-installed
⁃   configure:13637: checking where to find the target gcc
⁃   configure:13660: result: just compiled
⁃   configure:13679: checking where to find the target gcj
⁃   configure:13719: result: pre-installed
⁃   configure:13724: checking where to find the target gfortran
⁃   configure:13764: result: pre-installed
⁃   configure:13769: checking where to find the target gccgo
⁃   configure:13809: result: pre-installed
⁃   configure:13814: checking where to find the target ld
⁃   configure:13842: result: pre-installed in /usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin
⁃   configure:13856: checking where to find the target lipo
⁃   configure:13882: result: pre-installed
⁃   configure:13887: checking where to find the target nm
⁃   configure:13915: result: pre-installed in /usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin
⁃   configure:13929: checking where to find the target objdump
⁃   configure:13957: result: pre-installed in /usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin
⁃   configure:13971: checking where to find the target ranlib
⁃   configure:13999: result: pre-installed in /usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin
⁃   configure:14013: checking where to find the target strip
⁃   configure:14041: result: pre-installed in /usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin
⁃   configure:14055: checking where to find the target windres
⁃   configure:14092: result: pre-installed
⁃   configure:14097: checking where to find the target windmc
⁃   configure:14134: result: pre-installed
⁃   configure:14167: checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles
⁃   configure:14176: result: no
⁃   configure:14209: checking whether -fkeep-inline-functions is supported
⁃   configure:14228: /usr/bin/gcc -c -g -O2 -fkeep-inline-functions  conftest.c >&5
⁃   configure:14228: $? = 0
⁃   configure:14229: result: yes
⁃   configure:14426: creating ./config.status
⁃   
⁃   ## ---------------------- ##
⁃   ## Running config.status. ##
⁃   ## ---------------------- ##
⁃   
⁃   This file was extended by config.status, which was
⁃   generated by GNU Autoconf 2.64.  Invocation command line was
⁃   
⁃     CONFIG_FILES    = 
⁃     CONFIG_HEADERS  = 
⁃     CONFIG_LINKS    = 
⁃     CONFIG_COMMANDS = 
⁃     $ ./config.status 
⁃   
⁃   on huangxiaoshuaideMacBook-Air.local
⁃   
⁃   config.status:947: creating Makefile
⁃   
⁃   ## ---------------- ##
⁃   ## Cache variables. ##
⁃   ## ---------------- ##
⁃   
⁃   ac_cv_build=x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0
⁃   ac_cv_c_compiler_gnu=yes
⁃   ac_cv_cxx_compiler_gnu=yes
⁃   ac_cv_env_AR_FOR_TARGET_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_AR_FOR_TARGET_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_AR_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_AR_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_AS_FOR_TARGET_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_AS_FOR_TARGET_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_AS_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_AS_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_TARGET_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_TARGET_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
⁃   ac_cv_env_CC_value=/usr/bin/gcc
⁃   ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_CXX_FOR_TARGET_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_CXX_FOR_TARGET_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_GCC_FOR_TARGET_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_GCC_FOR_TARGET_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_GCJ_FOR_TARGET_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_GCJ_FOR_TARGET_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_GOC_FOR_TARGET_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_GOC_FOR_TARGET_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_LD_FOR_TARGET_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_LD_FOR_TARGET_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_LD_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_LD_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_LIPO_FOR_TARGET_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_LIPO_FOR_TARGET_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_LIPO_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_LIPO_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_NM_FOR_TARGET_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_NM_FOR_TARGET_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_NM_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_NM_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_RANLIB_FOR_TARGET_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_RANLIB_FOR_TARGET_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_RANLIB_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_RANLIB_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_STRIP_FOR_TARGET_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_STRIP_FOR_TARGET_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_STRIP_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_STRIP_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_WINDMC_FOR_TARGET_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_WINDMC_FOR_TARGET_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_WINDMC_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_WINDMC_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_WINDRES_FOR_TARGET_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_WINDRES_FOR_TARGET_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_WINDRES_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_WINDRES_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_build_configargs_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_build_configargs_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_host_configargs_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_host_configargs_value=
⁃   ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=set
⁃   ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=i386-jos-elf
⁃   ac_cv_env_target_configargs_set=
⁃   ac_cv_env_target_configargs_value=
⁃   ac_cv_host=x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0
⁃   ac_cv_lib_pwl_PWL_handle_timeout=no
⁃   ac_cv_objext=o
⁃   ac_cv_path_AR_FOR_TARGET=/usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin/ar
⁃   ac_cv_path_AS_FOR_TARGET=/usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin/as
⁃   ac_cv_path_LD_FOR_TARGET=/usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin/ld
⁃   ac_cv_path_NM_FOR_TARGET=/usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin/nm
⁃   ac_cv_path_OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET=/usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin/objdump
⁃   ac_cv_path_RANLIB_FOR_TARGET=/usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin/ranlib
⁃   ac_cv_path_SED=/usr/bin/sed
⁃   ac_cv_path_STRIP_FOR_TARGET=/usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin/strip
⁃   ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
⁃   ac_cv_prog_AR=ar
⁃   ac_cv_prog_AS=as
⁃   ac_cv_prog_AWK=awk
⁃   ac_cv_prog_BISON=bison
⁃   ac_cv_prog_CC_FOR_TARGET=i386-jos-elf-gcc
⁃   ac_cv_prog_EXPECT=expect
⁃   ac_cv_prog_FLEX=flex
⁃   ac_cv_prog_GCC_FOR_TARGET=i386-jos-elf-gcc
⁃   ac_cv_prog_LD=ld
⁃   ac_cv_prog_LEX=flex
⁃   ac_cv_prog_LIPO=lipo
⁃   ac_cv_prog_M4=gm4
⁃   ac_cv_prog_MAKEINFO=makeinfo
⁃   ac_cv_prog_NM=nm
⁃   ac_cv_prog_OBJDUMP=objdump
⁃   ac_cv_prog_RANLIB=ranlib
⁃   ac_cv_prog_STRIP=strip
⁃   ac_cv_prog_YACC='bison -y'
⁃   ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=/usr/bin/gcc
⁃   ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CXX=g++
⁃   ac_cv_prog_cc_c89=
⁃   ac_cv_prog_cc_g=yes
⁃   ac_cv_prog_cxx_g=yes
⁃   ac_cv_target=i386-jos-elf
⁃   acx_cv_cc_gcc_supports_ada=no
⁃   acx_cv_prog_LN=ln
⁃   gcc_cv_prog_cmp_skip='cmp --ignore-initial=16 $$f1 $$f2'
⁃   gcc_cv_tool_dirs=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/i386-jos-elf/4.6.1:/usr/local/libexec/gcc/i386-jos-elf:/usr/lib/gcc/i386-jos-elf/4.6.1:/usr/lib/gcc/i386-jos-elf:/usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin/i386-jos-elf/4.6.1:/usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin:
⁃   gcc_cv_tool_prefix=/usr/local
⁃   lt_cv_objdir=.libs
⁃   
⁃   ## ----------------- ##
⁃   ## Output variables. ##
⁃   ## ----------------- ##
⁃   
⁃   AR='ar'
⁃   AR_FOR_BUILD='$(AR)'
⁃   AR_FOR_TARGET='/usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin/ar'
⁃   AS='as'
⁃   AS_FOR_BUILD='$(AS)'
⁃   AS_FOR_TARGET='/usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin/as'
⁃   AWK='awk'
⁃   BISON='bison'
⁃   BUILD_CONFIG=''
⁃   CC='/usr/bin/gcc'
⁃   CC_FOR_BUILD='$(CC)'
⁃   CC_FOR_TARGET='$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gcc/xgcc -B$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gcc/'
⁃   CFLAGS='-g -O2'
⁃   CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD='-g -O2'
⁃   CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET='-g -O2'
⁃   COMPILER_AS_FOR_TARGET='$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gcc/as'
⁃   COMPILER_LD_FOR_TARGET='$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gcc/collect-ld'
⁃   COMPILER_NM_FOR_TARGET='$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gcc/nm'
⁃   CONFIGURE_GDB_TK=''
⁃   CPPFLAGS=''
⁃   CXX='g++'
⁃   CXXFLAGS='-g -O2'
⁃   CXXFLAGS_FOR_BUILD='-g -O2'
⁃   CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET='-g -O2'
⁃   CXX_FOR_BUILD='$(CXX)'
⁃   CXX_FOR_TARGET='i386-jos-elf-c++'
⁃   DEBUG_PREFIX_CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
⁃   DEFS='-DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\"'
⁃   DLLTOOL='dlltool'
⁃   DLLTOOL_FOR_BUILD='$(DLLTOOL)'
⁃   DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET='i386-jos-elf-dlltool'
⁃   ECHO_C='\c'
⁃   ECHO_N=''
⁃   ECHO_T=''
⁃   EXEEXT=''
⁃   EXPECT='expect'
⁃   FLAGS_FOR_TARGET=' -B$(build_tooldir)/bin/ -B$(build_tooldir)/lib/ -isystem $(build_tooldir)/include -isystem $(build_tooldir)/sys-include'
⁃   FLEX='flex'
⁃   GCC_FOR_TARGET='$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gcc/xgcc -B$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gcc/'
⁃   GCC_SHLIB_SUBDIR=''
⁃   GCJ_FOR_BUILD='$(GCJ)'
⁃   GCJ_FOR_TARGET='i386-jos-elf-gcj'
⁃   GDB_TK=''
⁃   GFORTRAN_FOR_BUILD='$(GFORTRAN)'
⁃   GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET='i386-jos-elf-gfortran'
⁃   GNATBIND='no'
⁃   GNATMAKE='no'
⁃   GOC_FOR_BUILD='$(GOC)'
⁃   GOC_FOR_TARGET='i386-jos-elf-gccgo'
⁃   INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
⁃   INSTALL_GDB_TK=''
⁃   INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
⁃   INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
⁃   LD='ld'
⁃   LDFLAGS=''
⁃   LDFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
⁃   LD_FOR_BUILD='$(LD)'
⁃   LD_FOR_TARGET='/usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin/ld'
⁃   LEX='flex'
⁃   LIBOBJS=''
⁃   LIBS=''
⁃   LIPO='lipo'
⁃   LIPO_FOR_TARGET='i386-jos-elf-lipo'
⁃   LN='ln'
⁃   LN_S='ln -s'
⁃   LTLIBOBJS=''
⁃   M4='gm4'
⁃   MAINT='#'
⁃   MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
⁃   MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE='#'
⁃   MAKEINFO='makeinfo'
⁃   NM='nm'
⁃   NM_FOR_BUILD='$(NM)'
⁃   NM_FOR_TARGET='/usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin/nm'
⁃   OBJCOPY='objcopy'
⁃   OBJDUMP='objdump'
⁃   OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET='/usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin/objdump'
⁃   OBJEXT='o'
⁃   PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
⁃   PACKAGE_NAME=''
⁃   PACKAGE_STRING=''
⁃   PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
⁃   PACKAGE_URL=''
⁃   PACKAGE_VERSION=''
⁃   PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
⁃   RANLIB='ranlib'
⁃   RANLIB_FOR_BUILD='$(RANLIB)'
⁃   RANLIB_FOR_TARGET='/usr/local/i386-jos-elf/bin/ranlib'
⁃   RAW_CXX_FOR_TARGET='i386-jos-elf-c++'
⁃   RPATH_ENVVAR='DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH'
```

--------split---------------------

I looked the similar question ,and google a long time ,but I'm not able to solve this question myself.Need HELP,really.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PFX/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PAT

add your lib path into your LD_LIBRARY_PAT, the PFX is your --prefix

Answer (score -1):

emmm,i still don't know what's wrong with it , but I used 'sudo port install i386-elf-gcc' and it worked out .